# Django CMS Plugin using Inline InclusionTag results in Orphaned Plugin

Tags: django, plugins, content-management-system, inline, orphan

I don't know what I am doing wrong as I have followed the documentation. I'm thinking it is some little thing. Here is the scenario:

The plugin is a Text Slideshow plugin. It allows the admin the ability to add text that will cycle like a slideshow.

The models are as follows:

```
class TextSlideshow(CMSPlugin):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    interval = models.IntegerField(
        default=5000,
        help_text=_('milliseconds between slides. (1000 equals 1 second)'))

    def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
        for slide in oldinstance.text_slides.all():
            slide.pk = None
            slide.id = None
            slide.text_slide_show = self
            slide.save()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.label


class TextSlide(CMSPlugin):
    text_slide_show = models.ForeignKey(TextSlideshow, related_name="text_slides")
    display_value = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    index = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_("Display order"))
```

The inline is:

```
class TextSlideInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = TextSlide
    fk_name = 'text_slide_show'
```

The plugin is:

```
class TextSlideshowPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = TextSlideshow
    name = _("Text Slideshow")
    render_template = "text_slideshow.html"
    inlines = [TextSlideInline,]
    module = _("Slideshow")

    def __init__(self, model=None, admin_site=None):
        super(TextSlideshowPlugin, self).__init__(model=model,
                                                  admin_site=admin_site)
        for inline in self.inlines:
            inline.placeholder = self.placeholder
            inline.page = self.page

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        slides = instance.text_slides.all().order_by('index')

        context.update({
            'model': instance,
            'placeholder': placeholder,
            'slides': slides
        })
        return context


plugin_pool.register_plugin(TextSlideshowPlugin)
```

The plugin works and will run flawless, but when the admin user adds text slides like so:

[image: Text Slideshow Plugin Admin]

When I run

```
./manage.py cms list plugins
```

I get this result:
`==== Plugin report ====`

There are 2 plugin types in your database

ERROR      : not installed

instance(s): 2

TextSlideshowPlugin 
  model      : cmsslideshow.models.TextSlideshow
  instance(s): 1

As long as i don't run

```
./manage.py cms delete_orphaned_plugins
```

my slideshow will stay in tact and will work fine.

The text slideshow itself is fine, it's just the inline'd elements which are orphaned.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing my code with a microscope several times while re-reading the documentation and many examples, I found my issue.

The issue is the child model should inherit from models.Model, not CMSPlugin

change:

```
class TextSlide(CMSPlugin):
```

to:

```
class TextSlide(models.Model):
```